# Postman - Use part of the response data from one test in another test

Tags: postman

I require help to execute a postman test which requires a response output from another test. I have checked with various forums but a solution is not available for this particular scenario.

Example

Test 1 response:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "email": "archer+qa01@gmail.com",
        "DocumentName": "tc",
        "type": "URL",
        "url": "https://localhost:8443/user/terms?statusno=a5f2-eq2wd3ee45rrr"
     }
  ]
}
```

Test 2:

I need to use *only* the `a5f2-eq2wd3ee45rrr` part of the response data from `Test 1`, this can be seen in the `url` value above. I need to use this value within `Test 2`

How can I make this work with Postman?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not completely sure what the response data format is from the question but if it's a simple object with just the `url` property, you could use something simple like this:

```
var str = pm.response.json().url
pm.environment.set('value', str.split('=', 2)[1])
```

This will then set the value you need to a variable, for you to use in the next request using with the `{{value}}` syntax in a POST request body or by using `pm.environment.get('value')` in one of the test scripts.

[image: Postman]

**Edit:**

If the `url` property is in an array, you could loop through these and extract the value that way. This would set the variable but if you have more than 1 `url` property in the array it would set the last one it found.

```
_.each(pm.response.json(), (arrItem) => {
    pm.environment.set('value', arrItem[0].url.split('=', 2)[1])
})
```

[image: Postman]

Comment: I got an error when i try to run with your suggestion Error: "There was an error in evaluating the test script:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Comment: @Archer I updated my answer because it seems like the response is not a simple object - Let me know if that works.

Comment: Getting the same error "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined".  I will try some other ways lets see if anything works with this scenario.

Comment: @Archer What does the actual response look like? Update the question to show this and someone can give you the correct answer.

Comment: I have updated my question with actual response I hope it will give clear picture. Thanks

Comment: @Archer Updated my answer with the response data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you get JSON response and then send JSON in body, I would do the following:

1) In test script(javascript):

```
var JsonBody = pm.response.json();
var strToParse = JsonBody.url;
var value = strToParse.slice(indexOf("?status=")+"?status=".length);//parse string 
//manually but you can google for a better solutions.
pm.environment.get("varName" , value)
```

2) You can use it! In scripts like: `pm.environment.get("varName")`, and everywhere else using `{{varName}}`

Comment: I have checked the script. I got an error it says "There was an error during runtime:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"

Comment: @Archer I think that's means you don't get expected response, try to use some console.log() in scripts to check values, and use console ctrl+alt+c in postman

Comment: Sure, I have checked it at console logs i got the same error. I will check it with other ways too.